# how to new an int array and set value in the same line with C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, initialization, int

In Java, I can do the things like the code below

```
int [] aaa = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

However, I don't know can I do the same thing in C++.

I do know I can do the similar thing with local variables.

```
int [] aaa = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

So, I want to know is there any method that I can new an int array and set the values in the same line in C++ just like what I did in Java.

Comment: `int* a = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};`. I don't think it's possible to omit the dimension. Better still: `std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

`std::vector` in C++ is a closer equivalent to Java's array than a raw C-style array.

Comment: I would have answered the same thing: it's time to get rid of C arrays when you have C++